# Stripe Checkout Plugin not showing in android device

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, stripe-payments

I have the following problem. I tried to start the Stripe integration on a physical Android device but it's not possible.

I have a project in **ionic 7 whith Angular** where I integrate Stripe using the "PaymentSheet" method, which in the web version within the browser works correctly making the connection with the .Net backend that is on an online server (It is not on localhost) of the which I receive the following data in the response: paymentIntent, ephemeralKey and customer.

When I execute it in the browser, the stripe plugin appears without a problem and I can even complete the payment process, but when I compile it for the native version of Android this fails, since the Plugin does not open on emulated devices or on physical phones.

I have really looked for many options but I have not had success, I would like you to help me with this, since I suppose the main problem comes from the following:

***No listeners found for event paymentSheetLoaded.***

I leave some screenshots here hoping they serve as a reference and can help me with this problem.

Thank you very much

**A fragment of the Logcat panel in Android Studio, where you can see the problems with the "Listener" call**

```
Capacitor/Plugin        io.ionic.starter                     V  To native (Capacitor plugin): callbackId: 118387073, pluginId: Stripe, methodName: addListener
Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     V  callback: 118387073, pluginId: Stripe, methodName: addListener, methodData: {"eventName":"paymentSheetCompleted"}
EGL_emulation           io.ionic.starter                     D  app_time_stats: avg=6485.01ms min=6485.01ms max=6485.01ms count=1

Capacitor/Console       io.ionic.starter                     I  File: https://localhost/8799.aeaa722d625ca6fb.js - Line 1 - Msg: paymentIntent:  pi_3O4oB0L9Q7sDxvs01Aig5CZZ_secret_qJb4neieSTGdbDzeKgtKNrsni
Capacitor/Console       io.ionic.starter                     I  File: https://localhost/8799.aeaa722d625ca6fb.js - Line 1 - Msg: ephemeralKey:  ek_test_YWNjdF8xTnptNXdMOVE3c0R4dnMwLGZVY3NNRHVpTW5HVlBOOGMwSUNtNWQ0ejd3dDl2cXg_00lRq8Ohky
Capacitor/Console       io.ionic.starter                     I  File: https://localhost/8799.aeaa722d625ca6fb.js - Line 1 - Msg: customer:  cus_OsZJwnLJzFmGA1
Capacitor/Plugin        io.ionic.starter                     V  To native (Capacitor plugin): callbackId: 118387074, pluginId: Stripe, methodName: createPaymentSheet
Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     V  callback: 118387074, pluginId: Stripe, methodName: createPaymentSheet, methodData: {"paymentIntentClientSecret":"pi_3O4oB0L9Q7sDxvs01Aig5CZZ_secret_qJb4neieSTGdbDzeKgtKNrsni","customerId":"cus_OsZJwnLJzFmGA1","customerEphemeralKeySecret":"ek_test_YWNjdF8xTnptNXdMOVE3c0R4dnMwLGZVY3NNRHVpTW5HVlBOOGMwSUNtNWQ0ejd3dDl2cXg_00lRq8Ohky"}

Capacitor/StripePlugin  io.ionic.starter                     V  Notifying listeners for event paymentSheetLoaded
Capacitor/StripePlugin  io.ionic.starter                     D  No listeners found for event paymentSheetLoaded
Capacitor/Console       io.ionic.starter                     I  File: https://localhost/ - Line 328 - Msg: undefined
Capacitor/Plugin        io.ionic.starter                     V  To native (Capacitor plugin): callbackId: 118387075, pluginId: Stripe, methodName: presentPaymentSheet
Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     V  callback: 118387075, pluginId: Stripe, methodName: presentPaymentSheet, methodData: {}
Capacitor/AppPlugin     io.ionic.starter                     V  Notifying listeners for event pause
Capacitor/AppPlugin     io.ionic.starter                     D  No listeners found for event pause
Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  App paused
Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Unable to find a Capacitor plugin to handle requestCode, trying Cordova plugins 2127678468
Capacitor/StripePlugin  io.ionic.starter                     V  Notifying listeners for event paymentSheetFailed
Capacitor/StripePlugin  io.ionic.starter                     D  No listeners found for event paymentSheetFailed
Capacitor/StripePlugin  io.ionic.starter                     V  Notifying listeners for event paymentSheetFailed
Capacitor/StripePlugin  io.ionic.starter                     D  No listeners found for event paymentSheetFailed
Capacitor/AppPlugin     io.ionic.starter                     D  Firing change: true
Capacitor/AppPlugin     io.ionic.starter                     V  Notifying listeners for event appStateChange
Capacitor/AppPlugin     io.ionic.starter                     D  No listeners found for event appStateChange
Capacitor/AppPlugin     io.ionic.starter                     V  Notifying listeners for event resume
Capacitor/AppPlugin     io.ionic.starter                     D  No listeners found for event resume
Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  App resumed
Capacitor/Console       io.ionic.starter                     I  File: https://localhost/8799.aeaa722d625ca6fb.js - Line 1 - Msg: Stripe Response:  [object Object]
```

**(FrontEnd) My payments.page.ts component:**

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Stripe, PaymentSheetEventsEnum  } from '@capacitor-community/stripe';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { first, lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pagos',
  templateUrl: './pagos.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pagos.page.scss'],
})
export class PagosPage implements OnInit {

  data: any = {
    "amount": 1200,
    "customerDto": {
      "email": "testemail@gmail.com",
      "name": "Jhon Doe"
    }
  };

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {
    Stripe.initialize({
      publishableKey: environment.stripe.publishableKey,
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  httpPostCreateIntent(body: any){
    return this.http.post<any>(environment.api2 + 'CreatePaymentIntentV2', body).pipe(first());
  }

  async paymentSheet()
  {
    try{ 
          
          Stripe.addListener(PaymentSheetEventsEnum.Completed, () => {
            console.log('PaymentSheetEventsEnum.Completed');
          });

          const data$ = this.httpPostCreateIntent(this.data);          
          const { clientSecret, ephemeralKey, customer } = await lastValueFrom(data$);

          console.log("paymentIntent: ", clientSecret);
          console.log("ephemeralKey: ", ephemeralKey);
          console.log("customer: ", customer);
        
          await Stripe.createPaymentSheet({            
            paymentIntentClientSecret: clientSecret,
            customerId: customer,
            customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey,
          });

          
          const result = await Stripe.presentPaymentSheet();
          console.log('Stripe Response: ',result);         
          
          if (result && result.paymentResult === PaymentSheetEventsEnum.Completed) {            
            console.log("All is ok!!")
          }
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
 
}
```

I have followed several tutorials trying to find a solution but so far, I have not been able to correct the error. I have tried the following:

- Add this line inside `AndroidManifest: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` (It does not work)
- Change the classpath of the `capacitor-cordova-android-plugins` `build.gradle` (It does not work)
- install versions of cordova instead of capcitor in my project but this is counterproductive since it breaks other modules that I have with capacitors. (It does not work)
- change the SDK version in variables.gradle to the following: `minSdkVersion = 26` `compileSdkVersion = 34` (It does not work)

Comment: What do you get when you log `result.paymentResult`? Have you also tried filing a github issue at https://github.com/capacitor-community/stripe? They'll likely be able to help as well

Comment: Thanks @karbi, I solved the problem and wrote my solution in the following answer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the problem, after several attempts and failures, the problem was solved by adding one more parameter to Stripe's **createPaymentSheet** function within the front in my payments.pages.ts file. The parameter I added is this: **merchantDisplayName**: 'Ionic plugins expert', and the function call looks like this in its complete form:

```
 await Stripe.createPaymentSheet({
            paymentIntentClientSecret: clientSecret,
            customerId: customer,
            customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey,
            merchantDisplayName: 'Ionic plugins expert'
          });
```